# squared complex norm of pde solution in wolfram-mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, complex-numbers, pde

Following problem:

I want to calculate the squared norm of a complex function f, in order to get a real solution. This means a want to calculate

```
    Solution = Re[f]² + Im[f]²
```

Actually the function is a vectorial one, so this should be applied to each component separately. I am looking for a command which solves this task, without remaining Abs[] functions or unsimplified results. 
Using Abs[] and a Simplify in advance, in order to declare real variables, works fine for expressions like

```
    P1 = DSolve[{I*psi'[t]==(m-I*gamma/2)*psi[t],psi[0]==1},psi[t],t]//Simplify
    S1 = Abs[psi[t]/.L1]^2
    Simplify[AL1, {t, gamma, m}\[Element] Reals]
```

But with harder expressions, or vectorial functions it stops with unsolved Abs[] terms, although variables were declared to real ones.
I got the problem with following example

```
    P2 = DSolve[{I*{psi1'[t],psi2'[t]} == 
                 {{m11 - I*g11, m12 - I*g12}, {m12 - I*g12,m11 - I*g11}}
                 .{psi1[t], psi2[t]},
                 psi1[0] == 1,psi2[0] == 0}, {psi1[t], psi2[t]}, t]
```

Which is nothing but the time dependant schrödinger equation of a coupled system with given initial conditions.
The right hand side is a matrix describing the coupling

```
    {{m11 - I*g11,m12 - I*g12},
    {m12 - I*g12,m11 - I*g11}}
```

multiplied with the vector with two time dependant functions. The solution should be vector, with real components containing, no remaining Abs[]-term and fully simplified.

```
    {Re[psi1]²+Im[psi1]², Re[psi2]²+Im[psi2]²}
```

Mathematica is able to solve this, but i don't manage it to give me the right output.

Comment: If you edited your post to say "For In[1] I want the output in this form, for similar but a little more complicated In[2] I want the output in this form, for similar but a little more complicated In[3] I want the output in this form and if you can do that then I will be satisfied" then someone might give it a try. It is great that you gave specific input examples, but showing exactly what "a quite elegant" result should be or what "working on components separately" would result in might help you get a solution. Simple concrete examples of what you want seem to help get answers.

Comment: Sorry about that. Is it more reasonable, now?